# Can quantum tunneling cause a particle to travel instantaneously across a distance essentially teleporting it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling, quantum-teleportation

Can quantum tunneling essentially teleport subatomic particles?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation

Comment: I am site there are duplicates of this question on the site, it would be worth reading those  to obtain  a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would concentrate more on the wave aspect than the "movement" of a particle. The particle has no definite position until we observe it, if you go along  what I think is the generally accepted interpretation of QM.

Particles don't have a definite trajectory, they have a probability of appearing at one place, then immediately after measurement they "disappear" on us again, until we take a measure at another place and they may or not be then appear at this new place.

The question of instantaneous travel then does not arise. The wave function associated with the particle produces a probability of a particle being found on the far side of a classically impenetrable finite barrier. That is essentially what quantum tunnelling is, i.e. a shorthand (and misleading if you concentrate on solely on the particle aspect) description of this process.

In addition, particles such as electrons are indistinguishable, so you cannot say for sure it is the same particle you observed earlier.

I apologise for the crudeness of this description, but perhaps someone can put it better, while still trying to answer the question in the same terms and level as the OP asks it.